# I want to change params[:my_locker] to name of column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm sorry for my poor English. And I thank you for your kindness to read it with patience.

Now I'm using sqlite3 in rails

I have `users` db and `lockers` db

In `index.html` view, there are many button like `A-1`, `A-2`, `A-3`....`A-10`.
I want when user click one of buttons in index.html view, controller get params of locker number like `A-10`. And my database, Locker, columns are consist of like `A-1`, `A-2`, `A-3` .....`A-16`.

So, when controller get params value like "A-10", it search for column name "A-10". after that saving the current_user.email value in that column which is "A-10"

It is my action

```
<form action="/locker/create" method="GET">
        <h3>Locker-A</h3>
        <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 400px;" id="first">
          <tr>
            <td id="A_1"><button name="my_locker" type="submit" value="A_1">A_1</button></td>
            <td id="A_2"><button name="my_locker" type="submit" value="A_2">A_2</button></td> 
            <td id="A_3"><button name="my_locker" type="submit" value="A_3">A_3</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="A_4"><button name="my_locker" type="submit" value="A_4">A_4</button></td>
            <td id="A_5"><button name="my_locker" type="submit" value="A_5">A_5</button></td> 
            <td id="A_6"><button name="my_locker" type="submit" value="A_6">A_6</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="A_7"><button name="my_locker" type="submit" value="A_7">A_7</button></td>
            <td id="A_8"><button name="my_locker" type="submit" value="A_8">A_8</button></td> 
            <td id="A_9"><button name="my_locker" type="submit" value="A_9">A_9</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td id="A_10"><button name="my_locker" type="submit" value="A_10">A_10</button></td>
            <td id="A_11"><button name="my_locker" type="submit" value="A_11">A_11</button></td> 
            <td id="A_12"><button name="my_locker" type="submit" value="A_12">A_12</button></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

and it is that I want controller do

```
def create
  @u = User.all
  @locker = Locker.all
  if @u.where(id: current_user.id).take.my_locker.nil?
      @u.update(current_user.id, my_locker: params[:my_locker])
      @locker.where(params[:my_locker]: current_user.email) # but it doesn't work.
      redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

How do I make params[:my_locker] to name of column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do, and please correct me if I'm misunderstanding the problem.

There are a few mistakes in your code that I want to address first.

```
@u = User.all
@locker = Locker.all
```

These lines are extra. You don't need to search for *all* objects before finding just one.

```
@u.where(id: current_user.id).take
```

... is the same as just saying ...

```
current_user
```

...because there will only ever be *one* user with the same `id` as `current_user`, which is `current_user`.

```
@u.update(current_user.id, my_locker: params[:my_locker])
```

You wrote that you're trying to update a `Locker`, but here it looks like you're trying to update a `User`. In addition, you're now finding `current_user` for the *third* time. It would be simpler to just do `current_user.update(....)`

Now, the line you asked about:

```
@locker.where(params[:my_locker]: current_user.email)
```

`.where()` is meant to *find* records, not *set values* for records. Potentially you want to do something like...

```
Locker.find_by(id: 10).update(params[:my_locker].to_sym => current_user.email)
```

I think `to_sym` is what you are really looking for in order to use `params[:my_locker]` as an attribute.

Here's what might be your finished code:

```
def create
  if current_user.my_locker.nil?
     Locker.find_by(id: 10).update(params[:my_locker].to_sym => current_user.email)
  end
  redirect_to :back
end
```

I realize I completely made up `find_by(id: 10)` for getting the right `Locker`, and it wasn't clear to me from your code how you wanted to identify the correct `Locker`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow! 'to_sym' is what I really looking for!!!!!!
I really nervous about my first question in stackover flow.
I learn from you a lot. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I want to set locker registration system for each students' associations in my university. My students' association id is 1. and others are 2,3,4..... . But now I want to service only to our association. So it doesn't need to identify relationalize  Locker with User. Anyway, Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 0):

> saving `current_user.email` in A-10

This is bad architecture on several levels, and is the *real* issue for your problems.

Firstly, you're trying to use a non `primary-key` to identify associative data. You should be using a [`foreign key`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) which ties directly into a primary key in the associated model...

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | x | y | created_at | updated_at
   has_one :locker
end

#app/models/locker.rb
class Locker < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | user_id | etc | etc | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :user
   scope :available, -> { where user_id: nil }
end
```

This will allow you to use the following:

```
#app/controllers/lockers_controller.rb
class LockersController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      @locker = Locker.all
   end

   def create
      # assuming you're using Devise (and have access to current_user)
      unless current_user.locker
         @locker = Locker.find(params[:locker][:id]).update(user_id: current_user.id)
      end
      redirect_to :back
   end
end
```

This will allow you to call `@user.locker`, instead of having to associate every single little item each time.

You'd be able to call your form as follows:

```
#app/views/lockers/edit.html.erb
<%= form_tag locker_path do |locker| %>
   <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :id, Locker.available, :id, :name) %> 
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will send a request to your `lockers#create` controller action with the chosen `:id` from your radio buttons. This `:id` will allow you to choose that locker, and set its user with the `.update` method.

--

The important thing to note here is that what you're currently doing is very inefficient.

You should definitely read up on [ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations), as you *may* be better with a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship:

[image]

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :lockers
end

#app/models/locker.rb
class Locker < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

This will allow you to associate many `lockers` with any number of `users`. Of course, I can provide more information if you require.

---

As an aside, your form could be made a LOT more efficient:

```
#app/views/lockers/edit.html.erb
<%= form_tag locker_path do %>
   <%= collection_radio_buttons :locker, :id, Locker.available, :id, :name %> 
   <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

You should always be sure to use Rails helpers ([`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) in your case), as these ensure all your HTML etc is processed properly.

In keeping with the [*DRY (Don't Repeat yourself)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) nature of Rails, you'll want to make sure you keep your code as efficient as possible. In the case of your form, you should either loop or use one of the `collection` form builder objects to keep it to one line.

Comment: Wow. your mentions is absolutely helpful. Thanks to teach me direction of study. In next week, when I finish my exams, I study your reference. 
Thanks a lot.
I love stackoverflow :D because of many kindful seniors like Mr. Rich peck and Mr.Lanny bose.